# Sliding fingers through view to read out individual components - Swift

Tags: swift, voiceover

I have a bunch of `UIButton`s scattered throughout a view controller. I want to be able to have users slide their fingers on the screen and have them read a button whenever they hover over one. I would also need it to work with VoiceOver. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: That's how VoiceOver on iOS works now.  There are many ways to navigate the screen.  You can swipe left and right to essentially "tab" to each element or you can drag your finger around the screen to explore what's there.  Many other ways too so I think you can already do what you want.

Comment: @slugolicious I don't want them to swipe their fingers. I want them to be able to keep their finger on the screen and move it around to see how the buttons are laid out.

Comment: Exactly. That’s what I said, *”or you can drag your finger around the screen to explore what's there”*